# Left Join multiple times 2 tables using same column ON

Tags: php, sql, left-join

I have a table A where several columns values should be replaced from corresponding id which are stored in table B as in this scheme:

```
TABLE_A
object_id   desc_id_1   desc_id_2   desc_id_3   desc_id_4   
zxy_34      9999        9567        5555        5556

TABLE_B
desc_id   complete_desc
1234      ABCD
9999      ZYXW
9567      POTG
5555      YUNR
5556      LPVR 
……..
……..
```

Final show than should be like that:

```
object    comp_desc_1  comp_desc_2  comp_desc_3  comp_desc_4
zxy_34    ZYXW         POTG         YUNR         LPVR
```

Is it possible?

At the moment tried something like that:

```
$sql="SELECT table_a.object_id, table_b.complete_desc 
FROM table_a 
LEFT JOIN table_b ON table_a.desc_id_1 =table_b.complete_desc";
```

It works ok using output this way:

```
echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>object</th>
<th>comp_desc_1 </th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                                                echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['object_id '] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['desc_id_1 '] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
                                                }
echo "</table>";
```

The problem is that don’t really know how to go further. 
Adding another left join like that stop the script and make load a blank page:

```
$sql="SELECT table_a.object_id, table_b.complete_desc, table_b.complete_desc 
FROM table_a 
LEFT JOIN table_b ON table_a.desc_id_1 =table_b.complete_desc
LEFT JOIN table_b ON table_a.desc_id_2 =table_b.complete_desc ";

…..

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>object</th>
<th>comp_desc_1 </th>
<th>comp_desc_2 </th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                                                echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['object_id '] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['desc_id_1 '] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['desc_id_2'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
                                                }
echo "</table>";
```

Some one can help me?

Comment: You need to put an "alias" for you to able to do that or you will get an ambiguous SQL error. SQL aliases are used to give a table, or a column in a table, a temporary name and works like an object wrapper.

Comment: Multiple columns `c_i` in a row that could be replaced by multiple rows with a single column `c` (plus possibly a column for i values) is a smell. This often arises from inappropriate pivoting (moving data from values to column names)--pivoting should be done for final display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is important that I urge you to restructure your "table_a" table.  It just isn't set up to run clean, efficient, concise queries.

To normalize the structure, I recommend these columns:

```
object_id
desc_id
desc_order
```

Then the "pivot" query that you desire can be executed with just one LEFT JOIN.

```
SELECT object_id,
       MAX(CASE WHEN desc_order = 1 THEN b.desc_id ELSE NULL END) AS desc_id1, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN desc_order = 2 THEN b.desc_id ELSE NULL END) AS desc_id2, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN desc_order = 3 THEN b.desc_id ELSE NULL END) AS desc_id3, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN desc_order = 4 THEN b.desc_id ELSE NULL END) AS desc_id4
FROM `table_a` a
LEFT JOIN `table_b` b ON a.desc_id = b.desc_id
GROUP BY `object_id`
```

[SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3c437f/1)

I can only hope that you aren't too far in your project to make this adjustment, because it will set you up for a much easier time developing in the future.  (Plus flexibility is improved -- if you decide you want more than 4 columns, you can seamlessly include 5 or more columns in the result set.

Comment: mickmackusa your solution is quite cutting edge technology to me in this context and show me what I think is a best practice to save time and computing resources. 
At the moment my table has four columns including one auto increment id (desc_id), group id ( object_id ), group description (object_desc) and object description (object_desc) thanks for your attention!

Comment: Are you comfortable with how to implement my suggested adjustment with your table schema? Or would you like more clarity? If you would like more guidance, please send your table structure and ~10 rows of data. Otherwise, if I don't hear back from you,  I'll assume that you are moving forward with confidence.

Answer (score 1):

You need to give each instance of `table_b` in your query an alias, otherwise it can't be known which one you are referring to. You also need to give the separate `complete_desc` values different names so they don't overwrite each other in the output array. Try something like this:

```
$sql="SELECT table_a.object_id, b1.complete_desc AS desc_id_1, b2.complete_desc AS desc_id_2
FROM table_a 
LEFT JOIN table_b b1 ON table_a.desc_id_1 = b1.complete_desc
LEFT JOIN table_b b2 ON table_a.desc_id_2 = b2.complete_desc ";
```

You also need to remove the spaces in the array keys in these lines:

```
echo "<td>" . $row['object_id '] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['desc_id_1 '] . "</td>";
```

they should be:

```
echo "<td>" . $row['object_id'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['desc_id_1'] . "</td>";
```

Comment: thank you Nick, at the moment am not able to test it, will tell you tomorrow. Just a confirm if you are still there, in select is correct to use b1.complete_desc AS desc_id_1 instead of table_b.complete_desc AS desc_id_1 since the complete name will be retrieved from the system at following step LEFT JOIN table_b b1, b2, b3 and so on? thank you again!

Comment: That is correct. If you use `table_b.complete_desc` the database does not know which `table_b` you are referring to.

Answer (score 0):

To get what you want, the JOINs need to be on the matching IDs, then get the respective description AFTER the join.  If a given "ID" may not be present, you would need a LEFT-JOIN meaning all records from the LEFT side (first table/alias) regardless of a match on the right (second table/alias).  Also, good to get into using aliases to simplify readability, especially on long table names, or when you need the same table multiple times such as this case...

```
select
      a.Object_ID,
      id1.complete_desc ID1Descript,
      id2.complete_desc ID2Descript,
      id3.complete_desc ID3Descript,
      id4.complete_desc ID4Descript
   from
      Table_A  a
         LEFT JOIN Table_B id1
            on a.desc_id_1 = id1.desc_id
         LEFT JOIN Table_B id2
            on a.desc_id_2 = id2.desc_id
         LEFT JOIN Table_B id3
            on a.desc_id_3 = id3.desc_id
         LEFT JOIN Table_B id4
            on a.desc_id_4 = id4.desc_id
```

Your join would never have a match such as ID Number compared to a description.  You need the ID from the columns in your Table_A joined to the ID column of TableB, hence multiple "alias" references for alias "id1", "id2", "id3", "id4"...

BTW, may people frown on too many underscores for tables and/or columns.  Get used to CamelCaseColumnNaming vs Using_Underscore_For_Columns.  Just a suggestion...

Comment: it is really helpful to know others way to manage the same issue, thanks you very much for your time DRapp